# Copy Paste Columns from one sheet to another sheet based on Autofilter

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy data from sheet to another sheet based on a filter.

Based on Column Q where autofilter criteria is "P", I need to copy column T & U from sheet ORD_CS to sheet Namechk.

Here is my code. No error but the entire column is getting copied.

```vb
Sub Macro26()
'
'Match Personal Names
'

'
  
    Dim i As Long, LR As Long
    Dim sht, sht1 As Worksheet
    
    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ORD_CS")
    Set sht1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Namechk")
        
    sht.Range("A7:AC7").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="P"
    sht.Range("T7:U99999").Copy
    sht1.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see how the whole column could be copied. Do you really mean all million rows?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sht.Range("T7:U99999").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy sht1.Range("A1")
```

instead of

```
sht.Range("T7:U99999").Copy
sht1.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub filter_paste()

Dim sht, sht1 As Worksheet

Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ORD_CS")
Set sht1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Namechk")

sht.Range("A:AC").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="P"
sht.Range("T7:U99999").Copy sht1.Range("A1")

End Sub
```